# Im getting exception Typeload what the exception can be?

Tags: c#

I added as reference 3 dll's: Google.Apis , Google.Apis.Translate.v2 , System.Runtime.Serialization

In Form1 i have one line:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            Translator.translate(new TranslateInput());

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Now the error the exception is on the first line in the class Translator:
The line that throw the error is: `var service = new TranslateService { Key = GetApiKey() };`

The class code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using Google.Apis.Util;
using Google.Apis.Translate.v2;
using Google.Apis.Translate.v2.Data;
using TranslationsResource = Google.Apis.Translate.v2.Data.TranslationsResource;


public class Translator 
{ 
    public static string translate(TranslateInput input) 
    { 
        // Create the service. 
        var service = new TranslateService { Key = GetApiKey() };
        string translationResult = "";

// Execute the first translation request. 
        Console.WriteLine("Translating to '" + input.TargetLanguage + "' ...");
        TranslationsListResponse response = service.Translations.List(input.SourceText, input.TargetLanguage).Fetch();
        var translations = new List<string>();
        foreach (TranslationsResource translation in response.Translations) 
        { 
            translationResult = translation.TranslatedText;
        } 
        return translationResult;
    } 
    private static string GetApiKey() 
    {
        return "AIzaSyCjxMe6RKHZzd7xSfSh2pEsBqUdXYm5tA8"; // Enter Your Key 
    } 
}

/// <summary>
/// User input for this example.
/// </summary>
[Description("input")]
public class TranslateInput
{
    [Description("text to translate")]
    public string SourceText = "Who ate my candy?";
    [Description("target language")]
    public string TargetLanguage = "fr";
}
```

The error is:

Could not load type 'Google.Apis.Discovery.FactoryParameterV1_0' from assembly 'Google.Apis, Version=1.1.4497.35846, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Tried to google for help and also tried to change the project type to x64 platform but it didnt help. So i put it back on x86

I have windows 7 64bit visual studio c# 2010 pro .net 4.0 profile client.

Cant figure out what is the error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error as reported in the above-posted messages is due to a local copy in the bin\Debug folder of your solution or project. Even though you attempt to clean your solution, such copies will persist to exist.

In order to avoid this to happen, you have to force Visual Studio to refer to the correct DLL by adding reference paths within a project properties. Unfortunately, if you got several projects within your solutions, you will have to set the reference paths for the projects one after another until completed.

Should you wish to know how to setup reference paths follow these simple instructions:

1.Select your project, right-click, then click "Properties";
2.In the project properties, click "Reference Paths";
3.Folder, type or browse to the right location of your DLL, click [Add Folder].

You will need to perform these steps for as many different locations you may have for each of your DLLs. Consider setting an output path under the Build tab of the same project properties, so that you may output your DLLs in the same directory for each of them, thus assuring you to find all the latest builds under the same location, simplifying forward your referencing.

Note this can only be one reason for this error. But it is sure that is has to do something with a wrong copy of the mentioned assembly.