# Can someone assist in understanding the cause of .Net Runtime Exception Info: System.TypeLoadException based on info provided?

Tags: .net, unhandled-exception, typeloadexception

I have an application that is triggering .Net Runtime Exception Info: System.TypeLoadException then crashes when trying to launch. I have tried to uninstal the application and reinstal. I did discover that it all started around the time it was updated. I have not tried to roll back to previous version yet only updated to a beta version which worked. If permissible, a side question is there any recommended materials that may guide me in understanding this even error? Especially if it can give a fairly good break down.

UPDATE: This is not our software and I have tried reaching out to the Vendor and waiting on a response again. Out of all our users we only have 1 person with this issue and version since being updated.

Thanks in advance.

```
Application: ndClickWinTray.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.TypeLoadException
   at ndClickWinTray.NdClickTrayIcon.SetDelegates()
   at ndClickWinTray.NdClickTrayIcon..ctor(ndClickWinTray.BusinessLogic.Infrastructure.Interfaces.IContainer, NetDocuments.Login.Contracts.Interfaces.IEventStream, NetDocuments.Login.Contracts.Interfaces.IUserAdapter, NetDocuments.Login.Contracts.Interfaces.IExceptionLogger, NetDocuments.Login.Contracts.Interfaces.IAuthenticationAdapter, NetDocuments.Login.Presentation.Infrastructure.IDialogFactory)
   at DynamicClass.lambda_method(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure)
   at SimpleInjector.Lifestyles.SingletonLifestyle+SingletonLifestyleRegistration`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].CreateInstance(System.Func`1<System.__Canon>)
   at SimpleInjector.Lifestyles.SingletonLifestyle+SingletonLifestyleRegistration`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].CreateInstanceWithNullCheck()
   at SimpleInjector.Lifestyles.SingletonLifestyle+SingletonLifestyleRegistration`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].GetInterceptedInstance()
   at SimpleInjector.Lifestyles.SingletonLifestyle+SingletonLifestyleRegistration`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].BuildExpression()
   at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.BuildExpressionInternal()
   at SimpleInjector.Internals.LazyEx`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].get_Value()
   at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.BuildExpression()

Exception Info: SimpleInjector.ActivationException
   at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.BuildExpression()
   at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.VerifyExpressionBuilding()

Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException
   at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.VerifyExpressionBuilding()
   at SimpleInjector.Container.VerifyThatAllExpressionsCanBeBuilt(SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer[])
   at SimpleInjector.Container.VerifyThatAllExpressionsCanBeBuilt()
   at SimpleInjector.Container.VerifyInternal(Boolean)
   at SimpleInjector.Container.Verify(SimpleInjector.VerificationOption)
   at ndClickWinTray.App.RegisterTypes()
   at ndClickWinTray.App.OnStartup(System.Windows.StartupEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1_0(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)
   at ndClickWinTray.App.Main()
   at ndClickWinTray.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

Comment: Without the code, we're not going to be able to solve this. Why aren't you taking it up with the vendor? Something to do with `NdClickTrayIcon` and `NetDocuments`.

Comment: I have and they are not always easy to deal with and have shared this info with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this your application or a 3rd party one?

TypeLoad exceptions occur usually when 3rd party references end up being mismatched.
You already hinted that this was observed aften an update, it sounds like a 3rd party dll is expected but unable to be loaded.

If this is your project code, then check that you have consolidated all your NuGet references to the same versions, this is a very common issue to experience.

Your particular issue is complicated by the implementation of dynamic script compilation, so we won't see the error during compilation, only at runtime.

Again, if this is your code, you should catch the exception and handle it, you may get deeper insights into the underlying cause.

Have you had a read through these posts on SO?:

- [How to debug System.TypeLoadException errors in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5691100/1690217)
- [Im getting exception Typeload what the exception can be?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10367911/1690217)

Comment: This is not our Application. I just finished testing the prior version 1.3 and there is no issue with loading it or the 1.5 beta. I have not and will now. Thanks for the info.

Comment: So far out of 800+ users, this one user is the only one with this specific issue. All others that have been upgraded to the same version has no issue.

Comment: There is clearly a component that was required but is missing, you should contact the developer for advice, devs will usually know pretty quick which components would cause these issues.

Comment: Thanks and I agree. I have sent a follow up request to speak with a Dev.

Comment: Could a permission issue cause this or firewall? As in preventing access to the location of these components.

Comment: Not usually, this is an expected reference on the local PC, usually looking in the bin folder and then the GAC, errors accessing resources on network locations would usually manifest as File Not Found or something like that. As the developer hasn't handled the error in a way that makes it easier to debug, you really need to contact them. There just isn't enough information from just this feed alone to further diagnose this. Reinstall all known 3rd party tools and references is the best we could advise from here.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was exactly what I was looking for and knew it was a longshot for an exact answer. It gives me enough ammo. I appreciate your information.